# ¿Como reiniciar un proceso con NodeJS?

Tags: nodejs, proceso

Actualmente, estoy haciendo un código para vigilar mis archivos de un directorio determinado y ver cuando ocurren cambios, para de este modo, reiniciar el servidor, el servidor es [express](/questions/tagged/express), y está corriendo desde otro archivo, el servidor viene siendo un sub-proceso, este es mi código:

*watcher.js*

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const BASE_DIR = __dirname;
const ENCODING = 'utf8';

var child_server = spawn('node', [`${BASE_DIR}/main.js`], { stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc'] });


child_server.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString(ENCODING));
});

child_server.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Traceback:\n');
    console.log(data.toString(ENCODING));
});

child_server.on('exit', () => {
    // aqui es donde trato volver a iniciar el proceso, pero no inicia
    setTimeout(() => {
        // console.log(child_server);
        child_server = spawn('node', [`${BASE_DIR}/main.js`], {stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc']});
    }, 2000);
    console.log('Restaring the server...');
});

fs.watch(BASE_DIR, {encoding: 'buffer', recursive: true}, (eventType, filename) => {
    if (eventType == 'change' && filename) {
        // child_server.kill('SIGHUP');
        child_server.kill('SIGINT');
    }
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log("Caught interrupt signal");

    child_server.kill();
    process.exit();
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
    child_server.kill();
    throw error;
});
```

Funciona casi bien, es decir, apenas se ejecuta, inicia el servidor con éxito, pero al detectar el cambio, mata el proceso del servidor pero no lo vuelve a iniciar.

La pregunta básicamente es ¿Cómo reiniciar adecuadamente un proceso con [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs)?

Comment: podria probar iniciando el proceso que esta matando con PM2, este modulo de node reinicia el app automatico

Comment: @Lcop , la idea es no usar alguna dependencia diferente a las librerias que trae consigo nodejs, de lo contrario utilizo un supervisor o un nodemon, algo asi...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const BASE_DIR = __dirname;
const ENCODING = 'utf8';

var child_server;

start();

function start(){
    child_server = spawn('node', [`${BASE_DIR}/main.js`], {stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc']});
    child_server.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{out(data)});
    child_server.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{err(data)});
}

function out(data){
    console.log(data.toString(ENCODING));
}

function err(data){
    console.log('Traceback:\n');
    console.log(data.toString(ENCODING));
}

fs.watch(BASE_DIR, {encoding: 'buffer', recursive: true}, (eventType, filename) => {
    if (eventType == 'change' && filename) {
        // child_server.kill('SIGHUP');
        child_server.kill('SIGINT');
        console.log("Reiniciando...");
        //Aqui lo reinicia.
        start();
    }
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log("Caught interrupt signal");

    child_server.kill();
    process.exit();
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
    child_server.kill();
    throw error;
});
```

Comment: No se que hiciste de diferente a parte de hacer la función para el start, pero me funcionó bien, muchas gracias, me gustaria mucho que explicaras que hiciste para no volver a cometer el error, luego de eso te marco la respuesta

Comment: Creo que en `on('exit')....` al instanciar un objeto dentro de mismo objeto causaba cierto error.

Comment: Ya acabo de entender el error, el problema es que al crear otra vez el proceso, no añadia los eventos que mostraran los datos en la consola, puesto los eventos en la funcion, si son añadidos, muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: Lo probe sin definir los eventos en `start()` y sigue funcionando, pero ahi no muestran los datos del `child_server`.

Comment: o sea, que el código, estaba bien pero no hacia log?

Comment: Nope, al no redefinir no mostrabas los datos. Pero de todos modos no funcionaba cuando se reiniciaba desde el mismo objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código veo que mandas un

```
child_server.kill()
```

Envía una señal al proceso hijo. Si no se dan argumentos, enviará `'SIGTERM'`.

Ten en cuenta que si bien invocas a la función kill, la señal enviada al proceso hijo en realidad no lo puede finalizar. De hecho, `kill` sólo envía una señal a un proceso.

Prueba con:

```
child_server.disconnect()
```

revisa el PID del hijo seguro no lo estás matando bien y no te está creando cuando reinicias.

Comment: Ya solucioné, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo quien terminaba el proceso era está linea ` child_server.kill('SIGINT');` y la señal es un SIGINT